# Savon + Rails 2 How to modify XML's request structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, savon

I'm using Savon to develop a Web Service Client. Since I'm a beginner I decided to try at first with an example WDSL, which in my case is:

> http://www.webservicex.com/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdl

My controller is very simple:

```
require 'savon'

class WebServiceController < ApplicationController  
  def index
    puts "web_service: IN"    
    client = Savon::Client.new do
      wsdl.document = "http://www.webservicex.com/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdl"
    end

    response = client.request :conversion_rate do
      soap.body = {
        :from_currency => 'USD',
        :to_currency => 'EUR'
      }
    end    
    puts response.to_hash;    
    render :text => response.to_hash    
  end
end
```

The XML produced by that code is:

```
<env:Envelope   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xmlns:wsdl="http://www.webserviceX.NET/" 
                xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Body>
        <ConversionRate>
            <wsdl:fromCurrency>USD</wsdl:fromCurrency>
            <wsdl:toCurrency>EUR</wsdl:toCurrency>
        </ConversionRate>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

However, the XML should be (and I know this because I'm using soapUI):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                    xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
<soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:ConversionRate>
         <web:FromCurrency>USD</web:FromCurrency>
         <web:ToCurrency>EUR</web:ToCurrency>
      </web:ConversionRate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I know my XML Request isn't working because I always get '0' (zero) as response, and with the "right" XML Request generated by soapUI I get correct values (such as '0.6959' ...).

Is something missing in my code?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two things:

1. you need to add :wsdl to the call
2. you need to make sure the spelling of the tags is correct

change to

```
response = client.request :wsdl, :conversion_rate do
```

and to

```
"FromCurrency" => 'USD',
"ToCurrency" => 'EUR'
```

that should do it for you.